# How do I change elements in a list when using imaginary components of numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a function within a program that performs calculations upon every element of the inputted list, where the list can be several hundred numbers long. I want to be able to take a list and find the elements where an imaginary component is negative. When this condition is true I then want to multiply both the real and imaginary components of that element by -1.

I've tried using the numpy package as nditer seemed to be a function that would suit my needs however this returns the wrong values and appears to improperly apply the condition.

```
for value in np.nditer( num_list, op_flags = ['readwrite'] ):
        if value.imag < 0:
            value * -1
return num_list
```

This condition check is the last operation that the function would do, so if the code could look like this then that would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
num_list= [ 4+5j, 3+2j, 7-2j]

def function( num_list )

    #other calculations are here
    #applies condition here 
    return num_out

print(num_out)
```

```
Output: [ 4+5j, 3+2j, -7+2j]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value * -1` is just the value of the multiplication, it's not actually replacing the `value`, perhaps you meant:

```
value *= -1
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np

num_list= np.array([4+5j, 3+2j, 7-2j])

def function(num_list):
    for value in np.nditer(num_list, op_flags = ['readwrite']):
        if value.imag < 0:
            value *= -1
    return num_list

print(function(num_list))
```

Output:

```
[ 4.+5.j  3.+2.j -7.+2.j]
```